# Why isn't $F(X) = 1$ when $F$ is the cdf of $X$?

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

This is a really simple question. For a random variable $X$ and $F$ its cumulative distribution function. Since $F$ is defined as $F(t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq t)$ for all $t$. I was wondering why we don't have $F(X) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq X) = 1$ because $\Omega = \{X \leq X\}$?

Comment: Try to write it down by definition. For $\omega\in\Omega$ we have that $X(\omega)$ is a constant real number, and $F(X(\omega))=\mathbb{P}(X\leq X(\omega))=\mathbb{P}(\{\eta\in\Omega: X(\eta)\leq X(\omega)\})$. There is no reason for this probability to be $1$.

Comment: Another way to answer your question is to go through the simple proof that for any $X$ with CDF $F$ the r.v. $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]\,.$

Comment: $F(X)$ is a (very special) random variable with values in $[0,1]$. For example, if $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$,work out what $F(X)$ is.

Comment: Is $F(X)$ equivalent to $F(X(\omega))$? And do we have $F(X) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega, \eta \in \Omega : X(\eta) \leq X(\omega) \})$?

Comment: No. $F(X)$ is a *random variable* while $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega, \eta \in \Omega : X(\eta) \leq X(\omega) \})$ is a *number*. Every commenter and the colleague who's answer you accepted emphasizes this fact. Therefore I find that question quite irritating.

Comment: Thank you I get it now! I was confused by the notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one downside of the shorthand notation in probability theory, like $\{X\leq x\}$ or $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$, that easily confuses new learners. To clear doubt, we must uncover the abbreviated part and see what $F(X)$ stands for.

Let us first write the event $\{X \leq x\}$ in full-form. This is the set of all $\omega \in \Omega$ for which $X(\omega) \leq x$ holds, i.e.,

$$ \{X \leq x\} = \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\}. $$

Then, the corresponding probability is

$$ F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\}). \tag{1} $$

Now, we would like to substitute $x = X$. Since $X$ is a random variable, which is a function of samples in $\Omega$, we may invoke the function notation and write $X(\bullet)$, where $\bullet$ is the placeholder for the argument of $X$. Hence,

$$ F(X(\bullet)) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq X(\bullet) \}). $$

Now we see why $F(X)$ need not be (and in fact, is in general not) equal to $1$, because $X(\omega)$ and $X(\bullet)$ need not be equal.

Comment: @DeadKarlMarx, Using a slightly different notation, $F(X)$ is a **function** on $\Omega$ mapping each $\eta\in\Omega$ to $F(X(\eta))$, i.e., $$\color{red}{\eta} \quad\mapsto\quad \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq X(\color{red}{\eta}) \}). $$ For example, if $\Omega=\{0,1\}$, then $F(X)$ is the function such that $$\begin{cases}0 \mapsto F(X(0))=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\{0,1\}: X(\omega) \leq X(0) \}) \\[0.5em] 1 \mapsto F(X(1))=\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\{0,1\}: X(\omega) \leq X(1) \}) \end{cases} $$ Try playing with other very concrete, simple examples to see how this works!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very clear now.